# How to get the current year from freemarker template

Tags: date, freemarker

I have use the  ${.now} to get the current time stamp inside the freemarker templates, but I want to know how can I get only the year?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Like `${.now?string('yyyy')}`. (Note that this will return a string, which is what you want if you only want to print it. If by any chance you need a number, so that you can do arithmetic with it, then it's `.now?string('yyyy')?number`.)